# How to transfer money from one PayPal account to another PayPal account?

Tags: php, paypal, cron

What I am trying to do is I have a one cron file, which check that the user requested payment if yes then this file transfer payment from admin PayPal account to user's PayPal account (of course only if admin account have money :)).

I check [Adaptive Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/#id094MB0Q0T5Z), but what I am trying to achieve is transfer money from admin's PayPal account to user's PayPal account. How to achieve this?

It is cron job. So there is no need of the approval of admin to transfer money. It is well handled in the project. Means directly transfer money from one account to another?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by admin's paypal account? does it refer to business,premier paypal account?

Comment: @Vimal, yes you are correct.

Comment: Actually, sender's (here admin) account type is a business account and receiver account type doesn't matter.  It is either Personal, Premier, Business, or a Student Account.

Comment: whats the issue in using Adaptive Payments then?

Comment: It asks for payment approval. I want it to transfer money without approval.

Comment: I am trying to transfer payment from one account to another user's PayPal account. How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like to transfer money between two paypal accounts without approval, then you will need to use `Implicit Approval` in [Adaptive Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/).

Implicit approval payments, in which your application is both the sender of a payment and the caller of the Adaptive Payments Pay API. In this case, PayPal makes the payment from your own account, which **eliminates the need for approval**.Try [here](https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/ap_implicit_payment/php?interactive=ON&env=sandbox)

Comment: This is possible using API REST SDK ??

Comment: no, it is not. Adaptive payments works only with classic API as of now.

Comment: i think the solution is here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/payouts/

Comment: is it possible to do a transfer from a paypal account to another one programmatically ? and using what paypal api?